# Does using Hive with HBase render faster response times and good for web applications?

Tags: hive, hbase, hdfs, freetext

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0r9s4iXwo0), it was indicated that Hive will render data with slow response times.

I would like to know if integrating Hive with HBase would be suitable for web-based live-running applications (CRUD), and secondly, if free-text searching (not just using LIKE), is possible?

In the video, they do indicate that it is read-based, but there are always updates :).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you got it wrong. Hive is not for applications that need fast response time. Check at 2:25 in the video.

Integrating hive with HBase, is just for data ingestion. You still need to contend with Hbase usecases while trying to read data. Given that, the response times in Hbase depend on how well you design your schema, like number of column families, row key design, usage of filters if any etc.

For free-text searching, you have solr which works on inverted index.

The answers are to your questions, and may be you need to read lot of material, before you can actaully use any of the mentioned technologies. Happy learning.